# How to have an array of objects in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my orm query :

```
$result = WpUser::select('wp_users.*')
        ->join('wp_usermeta as role_meta', 'wp_users.ID', '=', 'role_meta.user_id')
        ->where('role_meta.meta_key', '=', 'wp_capabilities')
        ->where('role_meta.meta_value', 'LIKE', '%'.$role.'%')
        ->get();
```

I want to merge these results with other arrays:

```
$users = array_merge($final, $result);
```

but I got this error:

> array_merge(): Argument #2 must be of type array,
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given"

I want to have an array of objects. ok, I can use `toArray(),` but it converts my objects to array!

Comment: Use `all()` method

Comment: You can also use `$users = $result->merge($final)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After performing a query to ORM you get an [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-collections), it wraps an array and add some functionality to it. If you'd like to get an array - just use [toArray](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-toarray) on the Collection object. For example:

```php
$result = WpUser::select('wp_users.*')
        ->join('wp_usermeta as role_meta', 'wp_users.ID', '=', 'role_meta.user_id')
        ->where('role_meta.meta_key', '=', 'wp_capabilities')
        ->where('role_meta.meta_value', 'LIKE', '%'.$role.'%')
        ->get();

$resultArray = $result->toArray();

$users = array_merge($final, $result);
```

Or better use Collection to work with and use [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-merge) method:

```php
// ...
$usersCollection = $result->merge($final);
```